# っぱち suffix - meaning and addition of さ suffix

Tags: words, suffixes

There are several words I've found that end in っぱち. **Does the suffix have any special meaning, like がち?**

[「やけっぱち」](http://zokugo-dict.com/36ya/yakeppachi.htm)
[「うそっぱち」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/19014/meaning/m0u/)
[「でこっぱち」](http://zokugo-dict.com/19te/dekoppachi.htm)

It also seems that these are na-adjectives, and [it is possible to add さ (for at least some of them) to turn them into nouns](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%87%AA%E6%A3%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B1%E3%81%A1%E3%81%95). **Is this addition possible for all っぱち adjectives?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no special meaning. As one of the linked entries says:

> ※「～ぱち」は語感に勢いをつけたり、意味を強調するもので、これ自体に意味はない。また、これを付けることで、特に意味が変わるものでもない。

I guess these might be originally coined as a wordplay so that it sounds like a person's name. ～はち/～ぱち (八) was a typical male name-suffix in the Edo period (eg 甚八, 新八). Since ancient times Japanese people often created meaningless phrases just because they sound nice ([examples](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%B0%E5%8F%A3)).

I don't think でこっぱち ("forehead") can serve as a na-adjective. For やけっぱち and うそっぱち, it's technically possible to add さ, but it's not common because they already have intense meanings (you don't hear 最高さ often, either).

Answer (score 2):

They are all used as intensifiers for noun there.
Therefore っぱち itself doesn't have special meanings like がち(serious?)

Since やけ, うそ and でこ are nouns not adjectivals(na-adjective),
You can't add さ to nominalize them.

Comment: Naruto-san. I think you should note that there are discussion on derivation of っぱち. To my knowledge,うそっぱちcan be abbreviation of 嘘八百 and やけっぱち